# selenium scroll by specific pixel values

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scroll

I see for python selenium I can scroll to element using

```
self.driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
```

Or using pixel value as

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, <vertical_position_to_scroll> )")
```

But is there way to scroll by specific pixel values from current element or current position. e.g. If I moved to element I want to scroll 10 pixel up from there.

Comment: Did my answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 11):

I would use `window.scrollBy(x, y)`

like this:

```py
#first move to the element
self.driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
#then scroll by x, y values, in this case 10 pixels up
self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, -10);")
```

[HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollBy) you will find the documentation on `scrollBy`.

Comment: The link to the documentation was helpful.

Answer (score -1):

to scroll to a specific element on a page:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div[2]/a")

element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
```