# Scrolling in Selenium C# Certain Pixels

Tags: python, c#, selenium, scroll

I am currently trying to scroll down in selenium C# using certain amount of pixels. How can I do this?

My last project, I have a working product in python, but this is the only issue I am having ever since I have switched to C#. I can't figure out how to scroll by pixel amount.

In Python, I was able to do:

```
pyautogui.scroll(-132)
```

and It will scroll down 132 pixels on the screen.

However, Im using selenium in C# and can't figure out how to do it in C#.

[picture of scroll bar which is inside the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3f6LK.png)

[THIS IS THE IMAGE OF THE INSPECT ELEMENT OF THE SCROLL BAR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfbAw.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51621817/selenium-scroll-by-specific-pixel-values

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I am using.

```
        public static void scrollDownByPixAmount(string value)
    {
        var windowScroll = string.Format("window.scrollBy(0,{0})", value);
        IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
        js.ExecuteScript(windowScroll, "");
     
    }

    public static void scrollUpByPixAmount(string value)
    {
        var value1 = "-" + value;
        var windowScroll = string.Format("window.scrollBy(0,{0})", value1);
        IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
        js.ExecuteScript(windowScroll, "");
       
    }


    public static void scrollToElement(string value)
    {
        IWebElement val = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(value));
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.MoveToElement(val);
        actions.Perform();
        scrollDownByPixAmount("150");
        
    }
```

Comment: Hey, this works for me when it's a main page for example or a news article that is long. However, there is a section that is embedded into the page that has a scroll bar  so whenever I try to do it, it doesn't work. Like I want to be able to hover the embodied document to scroll. I included a picture in my question for more info.

Comment: Updated my answer for another option. For what you are trying to accomplish, I would find the element inside that area and then scroll to it. Once I find the element, I like to scroll a little bit beyond it so that the element is clearly visible.

Comment: Hey, for some reason         Browser.scrollDownByPixAmount("150");
is the line that's giving me error. Do you know which package im supposed to install to use it. apprecaite your help tremendously

Comment: That is just the page I had it on. It is just calling the scrollDownByPixAmount method

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have a scrollable (div) element which you can pass as parameter (scrollable) to the function below.

```
public static void scrollDownByPixAmount(IWebElement scrollable, int pixelsToScroll)
{ //assuming your driver var is a static member of same class
    (driver as IJavaScriptExecutor).ExecuteScript($"arguments[0].scrollTop = {pixelsToScroll};", scrollable);
}
```

Note: the snippet above was not compiled.

Comment: hey, i included the screenshot of the inspect element of the scroll bar. do you know what exactly should i set the value of scrollable in this situation?

Comment: i think that is the graphical representation of scrollbar. you're after a containing div with an overflow: on it

Answer (score 0):

To Scroll down to certain pixel :
IJavascriptExecutor executes JavaScript asynchronously in the context of the currently selected frame or window.
scrollBy(0,1000) -> Scroll till 1000px

```
IJavascriptExecutor js = (IJavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,1000)");
```